# Rare but Abundant in Hill and Hole

Tags: riddle, word, pattern, word-property, letters

> I am uncommon,
> But a worthy goal.
> Rare but abundant
> In hill and hole.
> Who am I?

You may already know the answer, so the task is not to answer the riddle per se, but to solve the following 'What is a Word' puzzle, use the words in the puzzle to find another four word phrase (2 from each side), and explain how the phrase provides/validates the answer to the above riddle.

> What is an Uncommon Word?
>
> If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an Uncommon Word.
> Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Uncommon Words | Not Uncommon Words |
| --- | --- |
| FEW | LOTS |
| MANY | ALL |
| RARE | ATYPICAL |
| TIE | UNHINGE |
| IA | RI |
| BAGGED | TOSSED |
| DOOMED | PERISHED |
| GAPING | BEHOLDING |
| ADO (2x) | TWICE |
| SEAL | REFUSE |
| HAVE | LACKED |
| ROUNDS | TURNS |
| SPITS | SPITES |

> These are not the only examples of Uncommon Words, many more exist.

Hint:

> Teepee is an extremely common word.
>  Quitting is an extremely uncommon word.
>  Puddle is a quite uncommon word and also quite relevant. What property makes something uncommon?

Hint 2:

> I updated a word so that all the uncommon words are in an American scrabble dictionary rather than simply being American-English words, to help solvers identify them. Also added a very useful tag.